# Installation pdo_pgsql in Ubuntu10 not working

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

Am trying to install pdo_pgsql in ubuntu 10.04 and PHP 5.4.37. Actually the postgresql is installed and working properly with phppgadmin.

Now the problem is the pdo driver for pgsql is missing.

I installed pdo for pgsql, when I enter pecl install pdo_pgsql

```
# sudo pecl install pdo_pgsql
`pecl/pdo_pgsql is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.0.2
```

And also added a new pgsql.ini file in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ as
`extension=pdo_pgsql`

when I run phpinfo()

I can able to see

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pgsql.ini,
```

in `Additional .ini files parsed`

But I can't able to see the drivers loaded in PDO, only mysql and sqlite have been loaded.

Additional Message I got from server,

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

FYI,

Even I tried

```
# sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-pgsql: Depends: phpapi-20090626
              Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.30) but 5.4.37-1+deb.sury.org~lucid+1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Please suggest me how to proceed further.

I even restarted the apache and server itself.

Thanks

Comment: try sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql

Comment: Yes I tried, I got this message, 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-pgsql: Depends: phpapi-20090626
              Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.30) but 5.4.37-1+deb.sury.org~lucid+1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages

Comment: php5-pgsql required php 5.4 or higher, can you try it with `sudo apt-get install php-pgsql`

Comment: Yes am using PHP 5.4.37 and got the above error mention.

Comment: @Ramy : FYI, the pdo_pgsql is installed properly with wrong configuration path:  pecl/pdo_pgsql is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Try this

-----------------------------------------REMOVE

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-pgsql
```

Use this to remove `pgsql`
Depend what php try with `php5-pgsql` `php-pgsql` `php4-pgsql`

Comment: Actually pgsql is compiled in wrong folder. Actually I got this from phpinfo(): PHP Extension => 20100525 and PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS. But the pgsql was installed in API=20090626. Am not sure how to compile back to 20100525 ?

Comment: Why you dont use a fresh installed ubuntu ?  Clean. and reinstall all package

Comment: oh.. that's not possible. Am running around 20 websites there.

Comment: I entererd sudo apt-get purge php5-pgsql and try to install sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql, then i got the same error message mentioned above The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-pgsql: Depends: phpapi-20090626
              Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.30) but 5.4.37-1+deb.sury.org~lucid+1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages